# Inaccessible becomes successor of singular

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Is it possible, starting from any large cardinal assumption, to find a *countably closed* forcing $\mathbb{P}$ such that for some inaccessible $\kappa$, $\Vdash_\mathbb{P} "\kappa = \lambda^+$ and $\lambda$ is singular"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The following theorem is from a work in progress by Yair Hayut and myself.

> **Theorem.** If $\Bbb P$ is a proper forcing, and it changes the cofinality of $\kappa$ to $\mu>\omega$, then $\Bbb P$ adds a surjection from $\mu$ onto $\kappa$.

Now suppose that you had such countably closed $\Bbb P$, it is certainly proper. And it changes the cofinality of $(\lambda^+)^V$ to be something which is smaller than $\lambda$, and therefore collapses $(\lambda^+)^V$, and as a consequence it must collapse $\lambda$ as well.

(It should be remarked that a countably closed forcing cannot change the cofinality of something $\omega$ anyway.)

Comment: Wow!  Let me know when it is available.

Comment: Will do. This is just the first theorem of the paper, the rest is actually far more interesting. I think we're about halfway through, and hopefully in a month or so we'll have something on arXiv. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: (I also have to admit that I found it quite fun that this theorem popped up like this, something I did not expect!)

Comment: This is interesting.

Comment: @Mohammad: And that's the not-very-interesting part of the work. :-)

Comment: @Monroe: If you follow arXiv updates, then you might have seen that paper already. If not, http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02165