# Collapse an inaccessible cardinal to a successor of a singular cardinal

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Is it possible to turn an inaccessible cardinal in $V$ to a successor of a singular cardinal in some forcing extension?

Comment: Why not first collapse the inaccessible to the successor of a regular $\lambda$, and then kill the regularity of $\lambda$? (Or did you want the cardinal to be singular *in $V$*?)

Comment: Is the singular cardinal already given as singular? Or is it going to become singular later on?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184216/how-to-change-the-successor-of-a-singular-with-a-woodin https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178112/inaccessible-becomes-successor-of-singular

Comment: Yeah I had the singular cardinal in V in mind.

Comment: I have no idea how you'd accept Mohammad's answer if it is based on starting with a cardinal which is regular in V and then moving to a larger model.

Comment: Though I'd like to see how to do this directly, he did exhibit two models $(V_1, V_2)$ as in his remark 2, which is what I asked for.

Comment: Stationary tower forcing is another way.

Comment: @Monroe: That my first link in the above comment, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

One is suggested by Noah in his comment.

Another one is to use the supercompact extender based Prikry forcing of Merimovich. See [Supercompact extender based Prikry forcing](http://www2.mta.ac.il/~carmi/Publications/Merimovich%202011%20Supercompact%20extender%20based%20Prikry%20forcing.pdf).

There is also another idea due to Magidor which does the job. See [On a theorem of Magidor](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/Magidor's%20idea.pdf).

**Remark 1.** Note that in all of the above situations, the cardinal which is becoming singular is assumed to be supercompact in the ground model.

**Remark 2.** Using the above ideas and by finding suitable inner models of the final extension, in each case, one can find a pair $(V_1, V_2)$
of generic extensions of the ground model in which $\kappa$ is singular in $V_1$, $\lambda$ in inaccessible in $V_1$ and in $V_2$, $\lambda=\kappa^+$.

**Remark 3.** Let me show that some large cardinals are needed to get the result. Assume $V \subset W$ are such that $V \models'' \lambda > \kappa$ is inaccessible'' and $W \models''\kappa$ is singular and $\lambda=\kappa^+$''.

Assume there is no core model for a measurable cardinal and let $K$ be the Dodd-Jensen core model.  Pick some $V$-regular cardinal $\mu \in (\kappa, \lambda)$. Then $W \models``cf(\mu)=\theta < \kappa$''. Let $A \subset \mu, otp^W(A)=\theta$ and $sup(A)=\mu.$ By the covering lemma, there exists $B \in K$ with $A \subset B \subset \mu$ and $|B|^W = max\{ \aleph_1, \theta \}$. But note that then $|B|^K < \kappa,$ so $K \models`` cf(\mu) < \mu$, a contradiction.

Comment: Using the weak covering lemma, you can conclude that a Woodin cardinal is required (otherwise any successor of singular in $V$ is a successor cardinal in the core model $K$). Monroe Eskew's comment shows that a Woodin cardinal is sufficient.